# Azure function app, Powershell 7.2 dll module install

Tags: azure, powershell, function

I have this powershell script which works very well on my computer. I use the x64 and powershell 7.2.

The problem is when I publish the code to Azure, there is a module missing. The module is a .net System.Data.OleDb.

```
 ERROR: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The 'MSOLAP' provider is not registered on the local machine."
```

I have tried to add the .dll file to Module folder, that i created but function app doesn't load it for some reason.

Structure of the function app

- host.json
- local.settings.json
- powerbitablerefresh

  - run.ps1
  - function.json
- Modules

  - Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AzureClient.dll
- profile.ps1
- requirements.psd1

  - inside requirements I have:

```
'Az.Keyvault' = '4.*'
'Az.Accounts' = '2.*'
'Az.AnalysisServices' = '1.*'
'SqlServer' = '21.1.18256'
```

My question is, how do I install .dll on a function app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is that add the .dll files to the C:\home\site\wwwroot\ and then in the powershell script run it like this

```
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll")
```

It will then create a connection

Answer (score 0):

> how do I install .dll on a function app?

You can install .dll files by following below workaround:

- Firstly, Login to Azure
- Then open your Function App
- Then Click on Advanced tools , then click on Go
- Then Click on Tools, Then click on Zip Push Depoly like below:

[image]

- Then Click on your function app
- Then click on bin folder and after it opens, drag your .dll file over there and then you can reference them in your function app:

[image]

Comment: According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#function-app-level-modules-folder), there is nothing about bin folder. 
I tried the bin version but nothing happened with my .dll file. Then I have made a structure in my path /Module/oledb/System.Data.OleDb.dll.zip
I read that it needs to be a zip file.[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#language-worker-level-modules-folder) I use visual code for my powershell script deployment